# How do I fix these TensorFlow errors? (Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm very new to TensorFlow, and today I tried to install it and get it all running in PyCharm. I used the normal "pip3 install TensorFlow" that I found online. When I import TensorFlow in PyCharm, I don't get any import errors, but I can't get my sample code to run properly. **Does anyone know how I can fix this, or have any really good full tutorials for TensorFlow?**

By the way, I am using a MacBook Pro on macOS Catalina, and running Python 3.7.4. I'm also pretty new to using PyCharm.

## Code

```
# Import `tensorflow`
import tensorflow as tf

# Initialize two constants
x1 = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])
x2 = tf.constant([5, 6, 7, 8])
hello = tf.constant("Hello World!")

# Multiply
result = tf.multiply(x1, x2)

# Intialize the Session
sess = tf.Session()
# Print the result
print(sess.run(hello))
print(sess.run(result))

# Close the session
sess.close()
```

## Output

```
/Users/anttesoriero/PycharmProjects/TensorTest/venv/bin/python /Users/anttesoriero/PycharmProjects/TensorTest/venv/main.py
2019-10-31 22:06:28.027494: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-10-31 22:06:28.052950: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f9ca1b4fa30 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-10-31 22:06:28.052970: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anttesoriero/PycharmProjects/TensorTest/venv/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    sess = tf.Session()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I will also attach a screenshot below of all my code and the output.
[TensorFlow code and error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypuqT.jpg)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please add the TensorFlow version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using Tensorflow-2 and your code is compatible only for for tensorflow-1 cause there is no such thing Session in tf-2.

you need to switch from tf-2 to tf-1 to run your code.

Regarding this message-

```
Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
```

It is just a warning not as an error, this means you will get performance gain when you install TensorFlow by compiling the binaries and not with installing pre-compiled TensorFlow like using  `pip`